# jQuery multiple variable not working on same page

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery `$ var` in my codes but I have some external js file those are  using `$jx` as jQuery Var. Now My codes are not working , I am getting `$` not is a function. I removed all external js files then it is working. I searched for solution. Many people says " You can use your own var as jQuery/$ instead by using like `var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();`. But when I call this line in me page , my `$ var` is being removed and showing "$ is not a function " error. I made a simple code to explain this problem

Please Read and test my following codes.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//var $=jQuery.noConflict();
var $jx = jQuery.noConflict(); // this $jx var will be used in another plugins or codes

function test()
{
$("#test").hide();
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Click Me to hide box" onclick="test()" />
<div id="test" style="border:1px solid #0033FF; background:#999900; height:100px; width:200px; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:20px;">I will be hidden</div>
</body>
```

Run above codes, Click on the button, nothing will be happen. An error will be occurred.
Now just remove this line `var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();` then it will work. I did not use $jx here, but made it for others external scripts. so how can I use both $ and `$jx` in my same page?
What is my mistake ?.

My work has been stopped on the middle of the project.

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

[Rewrite it like this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.noConflict();


function test()
{
  jQuery("#test").hide();
}
</script>
```

It means that instead of `$` you will have to use `jquery` in your code whereever `$`, you needed to use.

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jx = $.noConflict();    


function test()
{
  jx("#test").hide();
}
</script>
```

Now it means that instead of `$` you will have to use `j` in your code whereever `$`, you needed to use.

Comment: But I need to use both <code>$</code> and <code>jx</code> on my page, <code>$("#test").hide();</code> and <code>jx("#test").hide();</code> because some others plugins are using jx and I am using $

Comment: why not use `jx("#test").hide();`? what error r you getting now

Comment: But I need to use both $ and jx on my page, $("#test").hide(); and jx("#test").hide(); because some others plugins are using jx and I am using $, If in future I will add another plugin that use another var $jq then what will be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();
$jx(document).ready(function($){

function test()
{
    $("#test").hide();
 }
});
```

As you have redefined $ as handle for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try `var jx = jQuery.noConflict();` instead of `var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();`

And later `jx("#test").hide();` instead of `$("#test").hide();`.

See also documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
var jquery = $;
jquery("#test").hide();
```

Comment: if `$` isn't a function, passing it through an intermediary var isn't going to fix anything.